# Solving $a_n = c_{n,n - 1} a_{n - 1} + \dots + c_{n,0} a_{0}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, recursion

I have been drawn to the art of solving recurrence relations from an unrelated problem in analysis.
Given real numbers $a_0$ and
\begin{eqnarray}
 & & c_{1,0} \\
 & c_{2,1} \quad & c_{2, 0} \\
c_{3,2} \quad & c_{3,1} \quad &  c_{3,0} \\
 & & \vdots \quad,
\end{eqnarray}
is there a way to explicitly solve $a_n = c_{n,n - 1} a_{n - 1} + \dots +  c_{n,0} a_{0}$? One can work out the first few terms:
$$
a_1 = c_{1,0} a_0 \quad; \quad a_2 = c_{2,1} a_1 + c_{2, 0} a_0 = \left(c_{2,1} c_{1,0} + c_{2, 0}\right) a_0 \quad ; \text{ etc.}
$$
However, I can't figure out how to extract a closed formula for $a_n$. I have gone through a bit of literature but it seems that not many results can be applied to this problem.

Comment: Seems to me $a_n$ is sum over all products $c_{e_1,e_2}c_{e_2,e_3}\cdots c_{e_{k-1},e_k}a_0$ where $n=e_1>e_2>\dots >e_k=0$ of all possible lengths $k$, which should be provable by induction. Not sure if you can find something more closed than this.

Comment: Thank you it seems to work, I will try to finish the proof by induction!